# jQuery change containing element's width with slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to have a button group with buttons where when the user hovers over them, more content slides in within the button using jQuery's `.show("slide", {direction: 'right'})`. As you can see in the Fiddle, I have it partly working, but when hovering over the button, the button immediately grows to account for the space where the text will slide to when it's done. Is there any way to have the width of the button follow the width of the sliding element inside it?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k7ypusdq/1/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#new-hidden").hide();
  $("#new-button").hover(function() {
    $("#new-hidden").show("slide", {
      direction: 'right'
    }, 300);
  }, function() {
    $("#new-hidden").hide("slide", {
      direction: 'right'
    });
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Passion+One');
body {
  background-color: #339999;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.big-button {}

.button-group {
  float: right;
}

.button-group a,
button {
  background-color: #9fc;
  color: #acc;
  font-family: 'Passion One', cursive;
  font-size: 24pt;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #3a8;
  border-bottom-width: 4px;
  float: left;
  width: auto;
}

.button-group button:first-child {
  border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
}

.button-group button:last-child {
  border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
}

.button-group:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <div class="button-group">
    <button id="new-button">
        <div style="float: left">Hello!</div>
        <span id="new-hidden" style="overflow: hidden;">
          I'm here too!
        </span>
      </button>
    <button>Middle</button>
    <button>Other Stuff</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify it by just animating the width and preventing text wrap:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="button-group">
      <button id="new-button" style="text-align:left;text-wrap:none;overflow:hidden;width:100px;height:60px;line-height:40px">
        Hello! I'm here too
      </button>
      <button>Middle</button>
      <button>Other Stuff</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>


$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#new-hidden").hide();
      $("#new-button").hover(function(){
        $("#new-button").animate({"width": 250}, 300);
      }, function(){
        $("#new-button").animate({"width": 100}, 300);
      });
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k7ypusdq/42/

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a dynamic approach that will get the width of any text you add without having to set a fixed width, you can do the following.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Store each hidden elements width within a data-width attribute. 
    // Set hidden elements width to zero.
    $('.btn-with-text .hidden').each(function() {

        $(this).data('width', $(this).outerWidth());
        $(this).css({'width': 0});

    })
    
    $('.btn-with-text').hover(function() {
        
        var hiddenBtn = $(this).find('.hidden');
        
        // On HoverIn apply and animate the stored data-width and apply left margin
        hiddenBtn.animate({
            marginLeft: 10,
            width: hiddenBtn.data('width')
        }, 300);

    }, function() {
        
        // On HoverOut set width and margin back to zero.
        $(this).find('.hidden').animate({
            marginLeft: 0,
            width: 0
        }, 300);

    });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Passion+One');
body {
    background-color: #339999;
}

.centered {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.big-button {}

.button-group {
    float: right;
}

.button-group a,
button {
    background-color: #9fc;
    color: #acc;
    font-family: 'Passion One', cursive;
    font-size: 24pt;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #3a8;
    border-bottom-width: 4px;
    float: left;
    width: auto;
}

.button-group button:first-child {
    border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
}

.button-group button:last-child {
    border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
}

.button-group:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}


/*
    Add this CSS
*/

button {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

button .not-hidden {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

button .hidden {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="button-group">
    <button class="button btn-with-text">
        <span class="not-hidden">Hello!</span>
        <span class="hidden">
            I'm here too!
        </span>
    </button>
    <button class="button btn-with-text">
        <span class="not-hidden">Middle</span>
        <span class="hidden">
          I'm Another One!
        </span>
    </button>
    <button class="button">Other Stuff</button>
</div>
```